# Javascript trouble passing argument

Tags: javascript, arguments

I have a Javascript function that I need to modify to accept arguments, one for the image id and the other for the select box's id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var dropd = document.getElementById("dd");
    image.src = dropd.value;    
};
</script>
```

So I'd like to be able to do something like

```
onChange="swapImage('this','<?php echo $image; ?>')"
```

I've tried changing it to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(pic,selectbox){
    var image = document.getElementById(pic);
    var dropd = document.getElementById(selectbox);
    image.src = dropd.value;    
};
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. Please help. Thanks

Comment: If you say that _this doesn't work_, then prepare for questions like _what do you mean?_. Anyway, alex's answer seems to point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the `'this'` into `this`, you can then reference it as any other element (skip the `getElementById()` stuff).